# How does the following work in Alkyne?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have the following reactions from a book, but it is not explained how the different substances come into being. I don't know what happens to $\ce{3H2O (H3O)}$ in the second line.

[image]

Comment: Pretty much the same thing as in next reaction - do you get the reaction with peroxide?